# How to solve a recursive convolution equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convolution, recursion, recursive-algorithms

In the most general case, I ask how to solve (either analytically or numerically) this equation for $x(t)$

$$x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t g(t-\tau) f\big(x(\tau)\big) d\tau$$

where $f, g$ are functions that make this convolution convergent (as an improper integral). In my application, I can further assume $g$ decays exponentially at $+\infty$ and is zero at $t<0$, and $f$ is bounded.

The **problem** that got me stuck, is that this definition is recursive. I have two ideas:

1. Guess a $x_0(t)$, then iteratively use this definition to get $x_1, x_2, \dots$ However the problem is I have to cut off $x$ and $g$ at infinity,and I cannot make sure the error induced by this cutoff is bounded.
2. Turn this equation into a differential equation. I prefer this solution, however when I take the derivative of the convolution, it becomes the convolution of a derivative $\frac{d}{dt} g(t-\tau)$, which makes it impossible to remove the integral.

The concrete equation I am trying to solve is from some [physics paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.121.027004) equation 4:

$$\Psi(t) = \lambda \int_{-\infty}^t K(t-t') \sin(Vt' + \Psi(t')) dt'$$

where $\lambda, V$ are constants and $K$ is "propagator" (a function of time with positive support).

Comment: Maybe look for a fixed point of the operator?

Comment: @copper.hat Exactly. Problem is the algorithm to find it.